# Specify Ordering to a DAO Method

Tags: java, dao

Suppose I have the following DAO interface:

```
public interface CountryData {
    /**
     * Get All Countries.
     *
     * @return A Collection of Countries.
     * @throws DataAccessException Thrown if there is an error communicating with the data store. The Exception's
     *                             Cause Exception can usually be examined to determine the exact nature of the
     *                             error.
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public List<Country> getAll();
}
```

Further suppose that I am abstracting this DAO because I might provide 2 implementations, one for a database and one for a web service.

I want to overload the **getAll** method to accept some sort of ordering parameter to indicate how the returned value should be ordered.

I don't want to tie the interface to a specific implementation however. For example, a database implementation would use an ORDER BY clause and would need a list of database columns and an order direction such as "ASC" or "DESC" where is a web service implementation will not.

What's the best practice to provide such a parameter without coupling the caller to a specific implementation?

**EDIT**

Small clarification to my question. I don't just want to specify a parameter to indicate the order direction, but also **what** to order on.

For example, suppose my Country model was defined as follows:

```
public final class Country implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Country() {
    }

    public Country(Country countryToCopy) {
        this.id = countryToCopy.getId();
        this.name = countryToCopy.getName();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

And I want to the returned value to be ordered by **name** in ascending order. I could use an ENUM, as suggested, for the order direction, but what would be the best practive to specify the property to order on without exposing implementation specifics?

Answer (score 2):

Either a boolean:

```
public List<Country> getAll(boolean ascending);
```

Or an enum:

```
enum SortOrder {
    ASCENDING,
    DESCENDING,
    RANDOM,
    NONE
}

public List<Country> getAll(SortOrder order);
```

Actually implementing this isn't the job of the interface. Just make sure any inputs the interface accepts can be handled by either of your classes.

Comment: Specifying an order direction through an ENUM is actually what I thought of, but how would I specify which properties on the model to order on without being implementaton specific (for example, pass the name of the database column) to the DAO? I edited my question to reflect what I need. Thanks for your quick answer by the way.